# Как перенести строку в коде

Tags: c#

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table_tovar] (id_category, name_tovar,price,id_klient,image,id_status,year)
                VALUES(@id_category, @name_tovar, @price, @id_klient, @image, @id_status, @year) ", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: А в чем вы пишете? Студия автоматически сделает правильный перенос. Вообще это делается через знак "+". Пример "начало строки" + "вторая часть". Где вторую часть уже можно утащить на другую строку.

Comment: В студии 2015 НО при переносе сразу подчеркивает

Comment: тут получается строковый параметр конструктора и не получается его перенести на новую строку (разорвать)

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой и быстрый способ - использовать [verbatim префикс](https://books.google.ru/books?id=6nuUCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT80&lpg=PT80&dq=verbatim+prefix+C%23&source=bl&ots=x8qYoAumvh&sig=npKhT7UientbsJtrppMku8Kn2mc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIkbLkg-XaAhXKEywKHcpiCyYQ6AEIZDAG#v=onepage&q=verbatim%20prefix%20C%23&f=false)(символ @)

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Table_tovar] (id_category, name_tovar,price,id_klient,image,id_status,year)
                VALUES(@id_category, @name_tovar, @price, @id_klient, @image, @id_status, @year) ", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: Алексей спасибо)

Comment: @user293746, незачто.

Answer (score 3):

Переносить строку можно двумя способами:

1. Использовать конкатенацию (`+`):

   ```
   string sample = "this is " +
                   "a " +
                   "string";
   ```
2. Использовать `@` перед началом строки:

   ```
   string sample = @"this is
   a 
   string";
   ```

   В этом случае обратите внимание, что если вы решите выровнять строку:

   ```
   string sample = @"this is
                     a 
                     string";
   ```

   То все пробелы будут включены в нее:

   ```
   this is                          a                           string
   ```